# Do multiple USB 1.1 devices on a bus require a hub?

Tags: usb, communication, usb-device

Can I simply attach multiple USB1.1 slave devices to a bus like I can with I2C (config A), or does the spec require a USB hub IC (config B)? Power in this application will come from a separate bus.

[image]

Comment: No. Despite the name, USB connections are always point to point. It just gives some aspects of the logical functionality of a bus.

Comment: Among other things, the hub provides the means for the host to enumerate attached devices and assign addresses to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Can I simply attach multiple USB1.1 slave devices to a bus like I can
> with I2C (config A), or does the spec require a USB hub IC (config B)?*

USB is a point-to-point system and not a multi-slave or multi-peer system so no, config A is invalid.